# How to rename a folder with an increment no using os.rename

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
n=0
def fetch_title():
  from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
  reqs = requests.get(URL).text
  soup = BeautifulSoup(reqs,"html5lib")
  for tag in soup.find_all("meta"):
      if tag.get("property", None) == "nv:news:title":
          title= tag.get("content", None)
          n=n+1          
          main_title = (n + ". " + title)
          return(title)
title1=fetch_title()
os.rename('NAVER_DONLOAD', title1)
```

So far i've tried this, to no avail, I'm getting 2 errors, I'll be passing a list of url from a txt file and it'll parse data from the links and save the data in their particular folder. but I'm unable to rename the the folder.

```
UnboundLocalError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-7-2521214d94f6> in <module>()
     71           main_title = (n + ". " + title)
     72           return(title)
---> 73 title1=fetch_title()
     74 os.rename('NAVER_DONLOAD', title1)

<ipython-input-7-2521214d94f6> in fetch_title()
     68       if tag.get("property", None) == "nv:news:title":
     69           title= tag.get("content", None)
---> 70           n=n+1
     71           main_title = (n + ". " + title)
     72           return(title)

UnboundLocalError: local variable 'n' referenced before assignment
```

Comment: You need a `n = 0` before your `for` loop.  The error `local variable 'n' referenced before assignment` means that Python is looking for the variable but it was not previously defined.  Also, you can use `n += 1` instead of `n = n + 1`.

Comment: variable "n" outside function is global; n inside fetch_title() is local variable, so it is different to the global variable; If you want to use "n" the global variable. add global n before n=n+1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple global n solved the problem along with `.join`

Here's the updated code

```
def fetch_title():
  from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
  reqs = requests.get(URL).text
  soup = BeautifulSoup(reqs,"html5lib")
  for tag in soup.find_all("meta"):
      n=0
      if tag.get("property", None) == "nv:news:title":
          title= tag.get("content", None) 
          n+=1          
          main_title = '. '.join([str(n),title])
          return(main_title)
title1=fetch_title()
os.rename('NAVER_DONLOAD', title1)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the `global` notation in order to work with the global variable `n` which is defined outside of your function `fetch_title()`:

```
n=0

def fetch_title():
  from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
  reqs = requests.get(URL).text
  soup = BeautifulSoup(reqs,"html5lib")

  # Use global instance of n
  global n

  for tag in soup.find_all("meta"):
      if tag.get("property", None) == "nv:news:title":
          title= tag.get("content", None)
          n=n+1          
          main_title = (n + ". " + title)
          return(title)
title1=fetch_title()
os.rename('NAVER_DONLOAD', title1)
```